# Haskell - Is variable a particular instance of data type

Tags: haskell, types

I'd like to ask, if there's any way in Haskell to find out, if a variable is an instance of some data type. For example, consider this situation:

```
data Shape = Square Int Int
           | Circle Int
           | Triangle Int Int Int

myShape :: Shape
myShape = Square 2 3
```

Is there any way for me to find out if `myShape` is a circle or a square?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can always write a helper function for this.

```
isSquare :: Shape -> Bool
isSquare (Square _ _) = True
isSquare _ = False
```

There may be some reason why you'd want to specifically ask this, but in most cases if you know you have a shape, you're going to need to handle all the possibilities:

```
doSomething :: Shape -> Shape
doSomething (Square x y) = ...
doSomething (Triangle x y z) = ...
doSomething (Circle r) = ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this. I was just wondering, if there's some another way. Something like `myShape == (Square _ _)` for example. But thanks!

Comment: @McDuck Not really, you need some form of pattern matching to check which constructor occurs in the value at hand. Still, this is not a commonly needed check: when we need to know "which constructor?" we usually also need its components. Reducing more informative types to booleans is usually a bad idea: this is called "boolean blindness". In many contexts, `case  of` produces better code than a chain of `if then else`.

Comment: @McDuck: If you want to write this inline, you can write this same `isSquare` function applied to a particular shape as a `case` expression, like `case myShape of { Square{} -> True; _ -> False }`. This uses explicit delimiters `{ …; …}` instead of indentation/layout, and the record pattern syntax `Square{}` as a convenient way to just match the constructor and ignore all the fields. If you need a function of type `Shape -> Bool`, e.g. to pass to `filter`, it can be written with `LambdaCase` as `\ case { Square{} -> True; _ -> False }`, equivalent to `\ shape -> case shape of { … }`.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you are confusing data constructors with subclasses in OOP. For example, in python;

```
class Shape:
   ...

class Square(Shape):
   ...

class Circle(Shape):
   ...


def area(shape: Shape):
   if isinstance(shape, Square):
      ...
```

This is not what your type means. To make it clarer:

- if you have something of type `Int` then it can take values like `-2, 1, 8, 0, 987, etc..`
- If you have something of type `Shape` then it can take values like `Square 3 5, Circle 3, etc...`

Therefore, your question is like if you have this python variable `a = 3` and you ask *Is `a` an instance of `7`?*. It makes no sense, the proper question would be *is `a` equals to 7?* or *is `a` less than 7?*, etc.... What you have to do is to define a function which determines when a values is or isn't a `Square`:

```
isSquare :: Shape -> Bool
isSquare (Square a b) = True
isSquare _            = False
```

Comment: You're probably right, I don't know the terminology very well, so feel free to edit my question.